# How to detect a touch on transparent area of an image in a (libgdx) stage?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Can someone please help to detect a touch on an image which I am using as an actor in a stage. The image is actually a long diagonal brush which has plenty of transparent area. The problem is when I touch the transparent area of the brush image it is also triggering the `ClickListener` of the image. I only want the `ClickListener` to be called when the visible image is touched, not the transparent part of the image.

I am using libgdx-0.9.4 libraries. Here is my simple piece of code.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ClickListener;


Image brushImg = new Image(ImageCache.getTexture("brush"));
brushImg.width = mStage.width()*0.75f;
brushImg.height = mStage.height()*0.75f;

brushImg.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void click(Actor actor, float x, float y) {          
        SoundFactory.play("brush");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Searched alot for this. May be there have a simple solution for this. Sorry that I am new to libgdx. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the libGDX Stage code has any specific support for setting a different bounding box/bounding region for an Actor.  But, there are some other things you can do to work around this.

First, in the `ClickListener` you can throw away touches if they're "invalid".  For example, if you have a simplified bounding area (in the case of a diagonal brush you might use an angled rectangle).  Or, if you want to be super precise, you can map the touch area back to the underlying texture and check if the pixel is clear or not.

From the libGDX API documentation, it looks like you can override the `hit` method on an Actor to change how touches are computed (and presumably the ClickListener will only be invoked if the hit succeeds).  This would let you test the intersection before the ClickListener is invoked (which could allow the touch to be forwarded to other objects on the stage).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think I can bound the diagnol rectangle of the image. But the pixel detection would be great if succeeded.